# Can inheritance be used for WCF fault details?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

In a WCF SOAP service, is it possible to use the known types mechanism to properly propagate FaultException with detail elements not explicitly mentioned in the FaultContract attribute?

Example:

```cs
// Basic service definition:

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesProvider))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(FaultBase))]
    void Test();
}

[DataContract]
public class FaultBase
{
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void Test()
    {
        subsystem.Do();
    }
}

// Elsewhere (in a subsystem):
[DataContract]
public class SpecificFault : FaultBase
{
}


public class Subsystem()
{
    public void Do()
    {
        throw new FaultException<SpecificFault>(new SpecificFault());
    }
}
```

Explanation:

The service contract defines a FaultContract with fault type FaultBase. The service implementation calls a subsystem that wishes to throw a specific type of fault named SpecificFault. Because the SpecificFault problem is local to the subsystem, it's impractical to list it with a FaultContract attribute.

The example code, as given, will result in a service and WSDL that knows nothing about the SpecificFault class.

If I use the known types provider to inject the SpecificFault class, the datacontract does show up in the WSDL.

The problem is that even when SpecificFault is present in the WSDL, the exception will show up on the client as a non-generic FaultException with no trace of the SpecificFault object.

Question:
Is using the known types system supposed to work for injecting fault details not explicitly mentioned in FaultContract attributes on the service method?

Note: I am aware that the client can not catch these exceptions using the base fault class, because FaultException does not inherit from FaultException. This question is about getting them to the client with the correct type, so that a client can catch it using either the specific type or the non-generic FaultException and reflect to find the exact type if required.

Comment: I wouldn't.  WCF uses a single fault to represent exceptions rather than sending c#-specific exceptions over the wire AND because services should be black boxes.  A client service is not going to know what to do with these exceptions anyway.  A fault is a fault is a fault

Comment: @MickyD I somewhat disagree. I never said anything about sending C# Exceptions, I'm talking about datacontracts representing additional details for different sorts of faults. The idea would be that all subclasses would be present in the WSDL just as other inheritance based data contracts. I don't see why a client cannot be coded to know about some specific fault details subclasses that might contain more structured information above a simple string message. One example would be to pass some identifiers concerning related objects so that an advanced clients can display a link to said object.